# Invalid operand for instruction movq using clang

Tags: assembly, clang, x86-64, att

I'm using the `movq` X86_64 assembly instruction on an Intel Core i5 with the LLVM-based clang-902.0.39.1 compiler.

The simplified code (at the my_asm.S file) in Intel syntax looks like this:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

#define a_const   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

movq   rax, a_const
```

I'm compiling with

```
clang -c -g -O3 -fwrapv -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native my_asm.S
```

The compiler gives me the following message:

> error: invalid operand for instruction
>   movq rax, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>   ^

I've also tried the AT&T syntax as suggested in the comments:

```
movq   $a_const, %rax
```

which gives the error

> error: unknown token in expression
>    movq $0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, %rax
>         ^

This instruction was used to work for Intel syntax since I included the 
`.intel_syntax noprefix` flag in the beginning of my .S file.
It seems that the error message started showing up after I updated my Mac OS (which updated the LLVM compiler, linker and Make).

Does anyone have a clue on what might be causing this?

Comment: IIRC Clang (like GCC and the GNU assembler) uses AT&T syntax for assembly by default. See e.g. [this article](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm) for some of the differences between AT&T and "standard" Intel syntax.

Comment: I tried the AT&T syntax as well and edited my question including the result.

Comment: If your file is in Intel syntax, then you need to put `.intel_syntax noprefix` at the top of it.  Your code block is missing that.  There may be a command-line option to set this, but `-masm=intel` just sets what the compiler-generated code will use.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was indeed using the `.intel_syntax noprefix`, I've just forgotten to add it to my example (edited now). 
FYI: I reverted my LLVM + clang to a previous version (clang-900.0.38) and surprisingly it is compiling again with Intel syntax style + movq instruction. Not sure why this works given your previous clarifications.

Comment: I said that based on clang 5.0.1's behaviour.  Maybe older versions allow size suffixes in Intel-syntax mode either on purpose or as a bug / design flaw.

Comment: @PeterCordes We're on the same page. LLVM/clang's team might either have changed their minds on the lastest LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1) or it was a bug and they've fixed it. Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me in AT&T syntax with `mov $-1, %rax` or `mov $0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, %rax`, or with `movq` instead of leaving operand-size implicit.

In Intel syntax, you can no longer use an operand-size `q` suffix to set the operand-size; it's implied by the register or with a `qword ptr` override on a memory operand.

`movq` is the mnemonic for instructions like `movq xmm0, rax` or `movq xmm0, xmm1` (two separate opcodes / instruction set manual entries that both use the movq mnemonic, one being the REX form of `movd xmm, r/m32`, and the other being the xmm/mmx `movq xmm, xmm/m64`)

```
mov    $-1, %rax
mov    $0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, %rax

.intel_syntax noprefix
mov    rax, -1
mov    rax, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

assembles just fine with `clang -c`, to 4 copies of the same instruction:

```
0:   48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff    mov    rax,0xffffffffffffffff
```

Note that `-f...` and `-O3` code-gen options have no effect when only assembling, not compiling C/C++, nor does `-march=native`.  Clang's assembler doesn't restrict instruction choice based on `-march`; it only sets what the compiler's code-gen will target.  (None of the options you gave *hurts*, but they have no effect with a `.S` except for maybe `-g`.)