# clang assembler error: ambiguous operand size for instruction

Tags: assembly, clang

I'm trying build [tinymembench](https://github.com/ssvb/tinymembench) with clang and am hitting errors on the assembly code. I can fix the easy ones (remove .func/.endfunc's) but the 'ambiguous operand size for instruction' errors on add and sub surpass my minimal assembly skills. I posted an issue on the repo but it's possible it's no longer being maintained.

Using this [source file](https://github.com/letrout/tinymembench/blob/master/x86-sse2.S) (removes the .func/.endfunc) I get errors like:

`$ clang-8  x86-sse2.S
/tmp/x86-sse2-dbaa71.s:86:9: error: ambiguous operand size for instruction 'add'
    add SRC, 64
        ^~~
/tmp/x86-sse2-dbaa71.s:87:9: error: ambiguous operand size for instruction 'add'
    add DST, 64
        ^~~
/tmp/x86-sse2-dbaa71.s:88:9: error: ambiguous operand size for instruction 'sub'
    sub SIZE, 64
        ^~~~
...`

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933466/invalid-operand-for-instruction-movq-using-clang) which looks similar, but I wasn't able to translate it into an answer for these instructions.

Comment: There's a `.set SRC,  rsi` inside an `#ifdef __amd64__`.  It looks like clang didn't do that?  It's supposed to be a register which will imply the operand size, but those error messages look like clang is assuming it's a symbol as a memory operand.  **Are those really the first error messages you get?**  I get `<instantiation>:2:1: 
 error: unknown directive
.func aligned_block_copy_movsb` from clang 7.0.

Comment: @PeterCordes: clang doesn't have its own assembler, does it?  I assume this is being processed by the system assembler, which maybe behaves differently than the assembler the code was written for?  Or, maybe the preprocessor is setting different macros than expected.

Comment: @NateEldredge: clang does indeed have its own built-in assembler, I guess so it can avoid going through the system assembler even for C that contains inline asm.  You can disable it with `-no-integrated-as`.

Comment: check this out before you post next time https://www.markdownguide.org/getting-started/

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ok, interesting.  A simple fix might be to go back to gas for the assembler files, since there isn't going to be any difference in the generated code.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's what `-no-integrated-as` does: it tells the clang frontend to still do other steps (like running it through the C preprocessor because it's a `.S`).  If there was any C/C++ source to compile, I think it would have the compiler emit asm and feed it to GAS, but since the input is already asm it just feeds the C preprocessor output to GAS.  (And yes, this file does need it, it uses `#ifdef __amd64__` and so on to choose which set of `.set` directives to use.)

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained.  Please copy the relevant sections of code into your question.  I have downvoted your question and will retract my downvote once your question is self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can fix the easy ones (remove .func/.endfunc's)

The `.func` macro includes a `.set SRC,  rsi` which defines registers according to the appropriate calling convention (x86-64 System V, Windows x64, or 32-bit with stack args).

Removing it leaves just an undefined `SRC` symbol which of course is treated as a memory operand.  (And `add mem, imm`  doesn't have either operand implying an operand-size, so it's ambiguous.)

Your "fix" introduced this bug.

---

**Use `clang -no-integrated-as` to use the system assembler instead of clang's built-in assembler.**  As expected, that builds https://github.com/letrout/tinymembench/blob/master/x86-sse2.S just fine on my Linux desktop with clang7.0.1.  (And system assembler = GNU Binutils `as` 2.31.1)

Comment: 'clang -no-integrated-as' works for me, thanks. I suspected I was somehow missing the .set calls but it looked like there were earlier references to those symbols in the code that did *not* throw errors, which threw me off the trail.

Comment: @letrout: GAS syntax doesn't require declaring unknown symbols (like NASM `extern printf`).  You can just `call printf` and it will emit a relocation for that symbol in the object file.  Or `mov rdi, [stdout]` to load the global `FILE*` variable.  Obviously you'd have a link error for symbols like `SRC` that aren't defined anywhere, but it's not an error to use undeclared symbols in GAS-style asm.  (Anyway, if this answers your question, you can mark it accepted with the checkbox under the vote arrows.)